# Can only spawn one object at once in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game I have a game object called `ExclamationMark` which I want to spawn above enemies heads when the player gets into range and they become "Alerted".

I've made this simple script to do that, but for some reason it will only work on one game object.

My enemy script:

```
void CheckForPlayer()
{
    // Define player and get position
    var player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    var playerPos = (int)player.transform.position.x;

    if (transform.Find("Graphics"))
    {
        // Define gameobject position
        var enemyPos = transform.Find("Graphics").gameObject.transform.position.x;

        // Define range to spawn tiles in
        var range = 5;
        var rangeInfront = enemyPos + range;
        var rangeBehind = enemyPos - range;

        if (playerPos >= rangeBehind && playerPos <= rangeInfront)
        {
            enemyIsActive = true;

            if (transform.Find("ExclamationMark"))
            {
                var exMark = transform.Find("ExclamationMark").gameObject.GetComponent<ExclamationMarkSpawn>();

                exMark.SpawnExclamationMark();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            enemyIsActive = false;
        }
    }
}
```

My `!` script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ExclamationMarkSpawn : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject spawnPos;
    public GameObject exclamationMark;
    public GameObject exclamationMarkAudio;

    public void SpawnExclamationMark()
    {
        StartCoroutine(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<CameraShake>().Shake(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f));
        Instantiate(exclamationMark, spawnPos.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        if (exclamationMarkAudio)
            Instantiate(exclamationMarkAudio, spawnPos.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        StartCoroutine(DestroyExclamationMark());
    }

    IEnumerator DestroyExclamationMark()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        var children = new List<GameObject>();
        foreach (Transform child in transform) children.Add(child.gameObject);
        children.ForEach(child => Destroy(child));
    }
}
```

Comment: what is transform.Find("Graphics") that you look for? if you have all the enemies objects call Graphics, unity only will take the first

Comment: Not the solution but: Instead of `transform.Find("Graphics").gameObject.transform.position.x;` you can simply write `transform.Find("Graphics").position.x;` as `transform.Find` already returns a `Transform`. The same way you can omit the `gameObject` after `Find("ExclamationMark")`

Comment: The entire block `var range = 5; var rangeInfront = enemyPos + range; var rangeBehind = enemyPos - range; if (playerPos >= rangeBehind && playerPos <= rangeInfront)` can be simplified to `if(Mathf.Abs(playerPos - enemyPos) <= 5)` ;)

Comment: In general you should strongly avoid all these `Find` calls .. they are pretty inefficient! Rather store the references one e.g. in `Awake` and then re-use them further on

Comment: Where is `CheckForPlayer` called? in `Update`?

Comment: Thanks guys I’ll implement those changes. Still fairly new to c#. And CheckForPlayer is being called in the update of the enemy script.

Comment: And the “Graphics” transform is the game object that has the sprite, collider and rigid body components for the enemy. I use the parent object to control universal parts of it and the the graphics object to control movement and interactions etc. I thought transform.find found the children? How do I only find a child with that name?

Comment: @Dom93 `transform.Find` only looks for the according name in the children. Therefore different children are returned for different `transform` (objects).

Comment: You don't need to destroy every child object. Just any root/parent will do. When you destroy a parent it destroys its children too.

Comment: but the parent is the spawn point, which needs to remain in game in order to spawn the ! when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be sure: I assume every player has its own instance of both of your scripts attached (some maybe nested further in their own hierarchy).

I assume that since you are using `transform.Find` which looks for the object by name **within it's own children**.

---

In general using `Find` and `GetComponent` over and over again is very inefficient! You should in both classes rather store them to fields and re-use them. Best would be if you can actually already reference them via the Inspector and not use `Find` and `GetComponent` at all.

In general finding something by name is always error prone. Are you sure they are all called correctly? Or are others maybe further nested?

> **Note:** [`Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html) does **not** perform a **recursive** descend down a `Transform` hierarchy.

I would prefer to go by the attached components. You say it has e.g. a `RigidBody`. If this is the only `Rigidbody` component in the hierarchy below your objects (usually this should be the case) then you could instead rather simply use

```
// pass in true to also get disabled or inactive children
Rigidbody graphics = GetComponentInChildren<Rigidbody>(true);
```

the same for the `ExclamationMarkSpawn`

```
// Would be even beter if you already reference these in the Inspector
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody graphics;
[SerializeField] private ExclamationMarkSpawn exclamationMark;
[SerializeField] private Transform player;

private void Awake()
{
    if(!player) player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    if(!graphics) graphics = GetComponentInChildren<Rigidbody>(true);
    if(!exclamationMark) exclamationMark = GetComponentInChildren<ExclamationMarkSpawn>(true);
}

private void CheckForPlayer()
{
    // If really needed you can also after Awake still use a lazy initialization
    // this adds a few later maybe unnecessary if checks but is still 
    // cheaper then using Find over and over again
    if(!player) player = FindWithTag("Player");
    if(!graphics) graphics = GetComponentInChildren<Rigidbody>(true);
    if(!exclamationMark) exclamationMark = GetComponentInChildren<ExclamationMarkSpawn>(true);

    var playerPos = (int)player.position.x;

    // always if making such a check also give a hint that something might be missing
    if (!graphics)
    {
        // by adding "this" you can now simply click on the message
        // in the console and it highlights the object where this is happening in the hierarchy
        Debug.LogWarning("graphics is missing here :'( ", this);
        return;
    }

    // Define gameobject position
    var enemyPos = graphics.transform.position.x;

    // Define range to spawn tiles in
    // this entire block can be shrinked down to
    if (Mathf.Abs(playerPos - enemyPos) <= 5)
    {
        enemyIsActive = true;

        if (exclamationMark) exclamationMark.SpawnExclamationMark();
    }
    else
    {
        enemyIsActive = false;
    }
}
```

The same also in `ExclamationMarkSpawn.cs`.

I would additionally only allow 1 exclamation mark being visible at the same time. For example when a player jitters in the distance especially assuming both, the player and the enemy, I would move the entire instantiation to the routine and use a flag. Especially since this is called **every frame** in `Update` while the player stays in the range!

Also re-check and make sure your enemies are not maybe referencing the **same** `spawnPos` and thus all instantiating their exclamation marks on top of each other.

```
public class ExclamationMarkSpawn : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform spawnPos;
    public GameObject exclamationMark;
    public GameObject exclamationMarkAudio;

    [SerializeField] private CameraShake cameraShake;

    // only serialized for debug
    [SerializeField] private bool isShowingExclamation;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!cameraShake) cameraShake = Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraShake>();

        // or assuming this component exists only once in the entire scene anyway
        if(!cameraShake) cameraShake = FindObjectOfType<CameraShake>();
    }

    public void SpawnExclamationMark()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ShowExclamationMark());
    }

    private IEnumerator ShowExclamationMark()
    {
        // block concurrent routine call
        if(isShowingExclamation) yield brake;

        // set flag blocking concurrent routines
        isShowingExclamation = true;

        // NOTE: Also for this one you might want to rather have a flag
        // multiple enemy instances might call this so you get concurrent coroutines also here
        StartCoroutine(cameraShake.Shake(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f));
        Instantiate(exclamationMark, spawnPos.position, Quaternion.identity);
        if (exclamationMarkAudio) Instantiate(exclamationMarkAudio, spawnPos.position, Quaternion.identity);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        var children = new List<GameObject>();
        foreach (var child in transform.ToList()) children.Add(child.gameObject);
        children.ForEach(child => Destroy(child));

        // give the flag free
        isShowingExclamation = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this;

```
if (transform.Find("ExclamationMark"))
{
    var exMark = transform.Find("ExclamationMark").gameObject.GetComponent<ExclamationMarkSpawn>();        
    exMark.SpawnExclamationMark(transform.position); //Add transform.position here
}

public void SpawnExclamationMark(Vector3 EnemyPos)
{
    StartCoroutine(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<CameraShake>().Shake(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f));
    Instantiate(exclamationMark, EnemyPos, Quaternion.identity);
    if (exclamationMarkAudio)
        Instantiate(exclamationMarkAudio, EnemyPos, Quaternion.identity);
    StartCoroutine(DestroyExclamationMark());
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve anything .. the `transform.position` is probably not the same as the `spawnPos.transform.position` ... otherwise OP would probably not have added a dedicated field for referencing another object

Comment: He wants "!" mark on top of any enemy that are close to the player. His code is really bad. If his algorithm is correct, this is probably what he wants.(+ offset from enemy's position). There is no way spawnPos can store all the enemy positions.

Comment: well `spawnPos` is probably a dedicated empty GameObject within the enemy prefab itself so yes it can store the position for each individual enemy

Comment: Just think about it and you will see it is impossible. Lets say there are 10 enemy prefabs and they all are set to spawnPos in the ExclamationMarkSpawn script. When you try get spawnPos value in ExclamationMarkSpawn script, which one of the enemy position will it get?

Comment: Because thats what he did in ExclamationMarkSpawn script.

Comment: He said there is only 1 "!" mark when he calls the function. Thats the expected behaviour.

Comment: Well every enemy will also have the ExclamationMarkSpawn script .. since according to the first script it searches for it in its children and calls the spawn if the player is close enough to it's position .. both scripts are attached to each of the enemy objects.. at least that's what I would expect reading them

Comment: Well that might work yeah. I doubt he did that tho.

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure OP did that since as said the first script explicitly searches the spawn script within its children (`transform.Find`) this would make little sense if it was placed somewhere in the scene